# Getting zip size error while executing ant to create jar

Tags: java, ant, jar

I have written an ant script to create a Jar file. This file is included in Eclipse project and works fine when ran through eclipse. But when it is run externally through command prompt, it shows following error:
Error Message: Problem creating jar: archive contains more than 65535 entries. (and the archive is probably corrupt but I could not delete it)

Jar Size: 130 MB.
Ant: 1.9.3
Java: 1.6

```
<property name="jar.name" value="SAFAL.jar" />
<property name="source.root" value="src" />
<property name="class.root" value="bin" />
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
<property name="jar.dir" value="C:\D\SAFAL-Exe" />
<property name="Main-Class" value="com.ktt.main.SAFALEval" />
<property name="conf.pkj" value="com/ktt/business/configurations" />
<property name="img.pkj" value="com/ktt/business/images" />

<path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="${class.root}" />
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean" description="cleans up build structures">
    <delete dir="${class.root}" />
    <delete file="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}" />
</target>

<target name="prepare" description="sets up build structures">
    <mkdir dir="${class.root}" />
</target>

<target name="compile" depends="prepare" description="Compiles all java classes">
    <javac srcdir="${source.root}" destdir="${class.root}" debug="on" optimize="off" deprecation="on" source="1.6" target="1.6" includeantruntime = "false">

        <classpath refid="project.class.path" />
    </javac>

    <mkdir dir="${class.root}/${conf.pkj}" />
    <mkdir dir="${class.root}/${img.pkj}" />

    <copy todir="${class.root}/${conf.pkj}">
        <fileset dir="${source.root}/${conf.pkj}" />
    </copy>

    <copy todir="${class.root}/${img.pkj}">
        <fileset dir="${source.root}/${img.pkj}" />
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile"> 

    <delete file="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}" quiet="true" failonerror="false" />

    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${jar.name}">

        <fileset dir="${class.root}" includes="**/*.*" />

        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" />


        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${Main-Class}" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
        </manifest>

    </jar>


</target>


<target name="run">
    <java fork="true" classname="${Main-Class}">
        <classpath>
            <path location="./${jar.name}" />
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>
```

Comment: I guess as running outside of Eclipse it runs from current working directory. So your relative paths (bin,lib,src,...) may contain much more files than from your project.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I am executing ant command from the directory where lib, bin, ant file are present.

Comment: One more observation: the jar file (although corrupted), which is created has same size as that of jar created through eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is resolved. I changed ANT version from 1.9.3 to 1.8.4 (1.8.4 is default eclipse ant version). Now ant build file is executing successfully.

Answer (score 3):

For creating ZIP/JAR files with more than 65535 entries you need Apache Ant with "zip64Mode" support - the first version that supports it is Ant 1.9.1.

Therefore I assume that your stand-alone Apache Ant version is too old.

See also http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html#zip64

Comment: I have ANT 1.9.3. Still facing the same issue. This is the line with the issue: <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" />

Comment: zip64Mode is by default set to 'as needed'.

Comment: zip64Mode goes into jar task as: <jar zip64Mode="as-needed" >[whatever]</jar>